# Agreement (Cohen Kappa) calculation of binary variable with multiple measurements over time

Tags: hierarchical-data, reliability

I would like to determine the reliability of a new dichotomous test vs another reference test using a Cohen Kappa approach.
However, in my dataset patients have been examined multiple times. I would therefore like to account for the clustering of observation in a specific patient.
I've not seen this approach previously in R packages such as `psych` or `irr`. Any thoughts?
Many thanks!